# \addplot + \pgfplotsretval = strange errors in pgfplots 1.14 and 1.15

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I used the following code some years ago, and it worked fine. I want to create a plot with a single data point, one coordinate of which is taken from a table using `\pgfplotstablegetelem` and `\pgfplotsretval`. However, now in `pgfplots` versions 1.14 and 1.15 this fails to compile with strange errors. In some cases it complains that it cannot parse '-5:5' as a floating point, even though I do not have such text anywhere in the code or data.

What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.15}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread
{
    x   y 
    1   10
    2   20
    3   30
}\data    

\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{y}\of\data
Value is \pgfplotsretval

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xbar]
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{y}\of\data
\addplot coordinates {(\pgfplotsretval,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three possible workarounds are shown below. The first one is very similar to your code, but instead of using `\pgfplotsretval` directly, I save it in a macro, and use the macro instead.

In the second I read the table directly, and use an `ifthenelse` in `x expr`/`y expr` to only use a specific coordinate.

In the third I use `x filter`, similar to an example in the manual (section 4.22 *Skipping Or Changing Coordinates – Filters*).

All three give the same output:

[image: plot with single bar]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread
{
    x   y 
    1   10
    2   20
    3   30
}\data    


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xbar]
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{y}\of\data
\pgfmathsetmacro\tmpval{\pgfplotsretval}
\addplot coordinates {(\tmpval,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xbar]
\addplot table[
    x expr={ifthenelse(\coordindex==0,\thisrow{y},nan)},
    y expr={ifthenelse(\coordindex==0,\thisrow{x},nan)}
    ]{\data};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xbar]
\addplot +[
  x filter/.code={
    \ifnum \coordindex>0
       \def\pgfmathresult{}
    \fi
   }
 ]
 table[x=y,y=x]{\data};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, Torbjørn! So it's a bug then?

Comment: @Danilcha I don't actually  know, because I don't know if it's supposed to work. You could always report it at https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/?source=navbar if you think so.

Comment: I got an [answer from the author](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/support-requests/17/): it’s similar to yours :)